# Installing pfSense on amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall, freebsd, pfsense

I was searching for AMI's with pfsense but seems like they are all vanished somehow.

How can I install `pfsense` on a FreeBSD ec2 instance besides creating a local image and then converting into raw than AMI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pfsense is it's own customised OS. You can't 'install' pfsense on an existing FreeBSD system as there is nothing released to allow you to do this.

This [pfsense Digest](https://blog.pfsense.org/?p=1132) post also lists the currently available official AMIs

The certified instance is

> It’s AMI ID id ami-6821b858

The public instances are

> US East (N. Virginia) - ami-11a58278
>
> US West (Oregon) - ami-3430ab04
>
> US West (N. California) - ami-0c417049
>
> EU (Ireland) - ami-9c1541ce
>
> Asia Pacific (Singapore) - ami-9c1541ce
>
> Asia Pacific (Tokyo) - ami-1f0e681e
>
> Asia Pacific (Sydney) - ami-6fdf4055
>
> South America (Brasil) - ami-cb13b5d6

Honestly, it took me 30 seconds to find this - you should really learn to use a search engine, they are the way forward.